# Sonarqube 4.2 X-Frame options and Cross site scripting vulnerabilities

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, csrf, x-frame-options

I am running a `Sonarqube 4.2` instance on a linux box. Since in our system we have a central portal page from where we navigate to all the child pages, I need to have sonarqube inside a frame. When I have an href, Sonarqube is denying which I guess is due to `X-Frame options` set as `SAMEORIGIN`. Any clue how we can modify this?

Also I need to provide `CSRF` protection in sonarqube. For jenkins, it comes with a built in option to enable `CSRF` protection. Does sonarqube have anything similar?

Thanks in advance for all the inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the X-Frame option, this has been fixed in SQ 5.1 and you can actually verify this on our [Nemo instance](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/).

For the CSRF protection, we have an open ticket about this: [SONAR-5040](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5040). Note that when an XSS vulnerability is discovered, we always fix it in the upcoming version as well as in the latest LTS version (currently 4.5.x).

Comment: Thank you Fabrice. I will update to SQ 5.1. How do I change the X-Frame option to ALLOW-FROM?

Comment: Hi @Fabrice, Could you please help me with the above question.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I wasn't clear enough. Before SQ 5.1, X-Frame option was not set, which could be an issue. Now, in 5.1, it is always set to SAMEORIGIN for security reasons (=> it is not configurable).

Comment: Hi Fabrice, for CSRF, I can use LTS version 4.5.x to get over it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue trying to get the responses from a SonarQube instance to display when placed in an iframe consumed by an internal dashboard application.

While the `'X-Frames-Option'` isn't explictly configurable in SonarQube, these two steps will allow you to display the response from a SonarQube server in an iframe:

1. Edit the `environment.rb` script in the `<SonarQube-Home>\web\WEB-INF\config` directory, commenting out the `'X-Frames-Option'` header assignment (or changing the value to `'ALLOW-FROM'` with the appropriate URL exclusion):

   ```
   # Clickjacking protection
   # See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Protection_for_Java_EE
   # headers['X-Frame-Options']='SAMEORIGIN'
   ```
2. Either comment out the existing filter configuration in the `<SonarQube-Home>\web\WEB-INF\web.xml` file (not recommended) or write your own `Filter` implementation and replace the existing configuration:

   `<filter>
        <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.sonar.server.platform.SecurityServletFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>`

   with your own (example):

   `<filter>
     <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>com.foo.MySecurityServletFilter</filter-class>
     <init-param>
       <param-name>X-Content-Type-Options</param-name>
       <param-value>nosniff</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
       <param-name>X-XSS-Protection</param-name>
       <param-value>1; mode=block</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
       <param-name>X-Frame-Options</param-name>
       <param-value>ALLOW-FROM</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
       <param-name>allow-from-uri</param-name>
       <param-value>http://internal.foo.com</param-value>
     </init-param>
   </filter>`

   The initialization parameters must, of course, be supported by your custom `filter` implementation.
3. I created a simple jar containing my filter and copied it to the `<SonarQube-Home>\lib\server` directory.